# How to disable stdout buffer when running shell

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am using Python to call a Shell script with

```
def run_command(cmd):
    print "Start to run: " + cmd
    run = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        line = run.stdout.readline().decode()[:-1]
        if line == '' and run.poll() is not None:
            break
        print line # print the log from shell
    recode = run.returncode
    if recode != 0:
        raise Exception("Error occurs!")

    print "End to run: " + cmd
```

Then I run

```
run_command("sh /home/tome/a.sh")
```

I notice the console output from a.sh is not in real time, looks like that there is a buffer for the stdout and when the stdout buffer is full, then the output is printed out.

I would ask how to disable the shell stdout buffer in my script a.sh

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The buffering in question would largely be a problem on the script's side, not the Python side; while Python would buffer the reads, it wouldn't block unless the buffer was emptied and there was nothing available to read.

So really, you need to disable buffering in the script itself. Adding [`stdbuf -oL`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) (or `-o0` for completely unbuffered, but line buffering should cover you since you read by line as well) to your commands should help in some cases (where the programs don't adjust their own buffering internally).

If you're seeing this behavior only by looking at Python's output, be aware that Python itself can buffer output as well. You can disable this by passing `-u` when running Python, or setting the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` before running it, or from within a script, you can manually call `sys.stdout.flush()` after any writes (direct, or implicit via `print`) to stdout. On modern Python, `print` takes an argument to force a `flush` after printing, but since you're on Python 2.x, that's not an option.

Comment: Thanks @shadowranger for the helpful answer, let me try.

Comment: That's too bad.. When I set the command as `stdbuf -o0 sh abc.sh`, the output is still buffered. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: @Tom: Whether `stdbuf` works depends on the actual programs being run; if they adjust their own buffering internally, at runtime, then `stdbuf`'s changes get undone. If they don't use standard streams, the changes don't affect their I/O at all. The `stdbuf` man page has a note on this, mentioning `tee`, `dd` and `cat` as being specific offenders, but those are just limited examples.

Comment: Thanks @hadowranger, When I run the python(which is calling shell) directy, it will output in real time, but when I run it in our scheduler system, then the output is buffered, I will investigite more to find out how to make it work.

Comment: When I am running python in interactive mode, then the buffer is disabled, but when I run python in non-interactive mode, then the buffer is not disabled, Even I have used `unbuffer sh run.sh a b c`,it also doesn't take effect. Not sure how to fix now.

Comment: @Tom: When you run with `shell=True`, there is going to be another layer of shell around you that won't be unbuffered. Perhaps remove `shell=True`, and split your command manually (e.g. [with shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)), so you can run `Popen(['stdbuf', '-o0'] + shlex.split(cmd), ...)` and avoid additional shell wrapping that might interfere with buffering. You might also want to test setting the environment variable `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` just to ensure Python's own buffering isn't screwing with you; you might be seeing delayed Python output.

Comment: @Tom: I realized it's likely you're seeing this by looking at Python's own output, in which case you may need to ensure Python either isn't buffering or explicitly flushes as needed. I've edited the answer to include that info.

Comment: Thanks @shadowranger for the answer, it works, thanks very much!