# Bash Script slows down executed program

Tags: bash, time

I have a program where i test different data sets and configuration. I have a script to execute all of those.

imagine my code as :

```
start = omp_get_wtime()
  function()
end = omp_get_wtime() 
print(end-start)
```

and the bash script as

```
for a in "${first_option[@]}"
do 
  for b in "${second_option[@]}"
  do 
    for c in "${third_option[@]}"
    do
       printf("$a $b $c \n")
       ./exe $a $b $c >> logs.out 
    done 
  done
done
```

now when i execute the exact same configurations by hand, i get varying results from 10 seconds to 0.05 seconds but when i execute the script, i get the same results on the up side but for some reason i can't get any timings lower than 1 seconds. All the configurations that manually compute at less than a second get written in the file at 1.001; 1.102; 0.999 ect...

Any ideas of what is going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Are the arrays huge? Keeping them in memory is probably a problem.

Comment: You go through all this trouble to quote the arrays ... and then botch it by not quoting the final variables inside the loop! [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: That `printf` is a syntax error. The proper syntax would be `printf "%s %s %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"` where we also take care to avoid putting data in the format string. (You could use a different format specifier than `%s` if the values are always numbers, for example.)

Comment: I've got about 10 arrays with 5 elements each so i dont think that could saturate my memory. And i don't see how a slow bash script will change something on the time measure of a different process

Comment: Thanks for the rest of the information, i'll change the code to fix that but my problem doesn't come from this since i know it executes correctly

Comment: Indeed, 30 array elements should barely be noticeable. The problem is probably not with your Bash script.

Comment: Appending to the output file is also a bottleneck, especially if the log is large. You can avoid that by moving `>> logs.out` to after the last `done` (and probably then replace the `>>` with `>` to replace the previous log?)

Comment: log is also quite small, usually 10 lines with 1 timer per line and moving it to a `>` at the end will have me change everything about the production code , especially when the code doesn't seem the have problems when it is manually executed...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to  remove the ">> logs.out" to see what happens with the speed.

From there you can try several options:

- Replace ">> log.out" with "| tee -a log.out"
- Investigate stdbuf and if your code is python, look at "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" shell variable. See also: [How to disable stdout buffer when running shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829831/how-to-disable-stdout-buffer-when-running-shell)
- Redirect bash print command with ">&2" (write to stderr) and move ">> log.out" or "| tee -a log.out" behind the last "done"
- You can probably see what is causing the delay by using:

  ```
    strace -f -t bash -c "<your bash script>" | tee /tmp/strace.log
  ```

  With a little luck you will see which system call is causing the delay on the bottom of the screen. But it is a lot of information to process. Alternatively look for the name of your "./exe" in "/tmp/strace.log" after tracing is done. And then look for the system calls after invocation (process start of ./exe) that eat most time. Could be just many calls ... Don't spent to much time on this if you don't have the stomach for it.

Comment: The code is in Fortran. 
I have removed the ">>" to just print to terminal to try it and i still get 1 seconds output

Comment: So then it is probably buffering to output, try the ">&2" of the third suggestion, while keeping ">> out.log" removed. Or try setting the GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL environment variable to 'y', 'Y' or 1.

Comment: Didn't work either, still output 1 second of execution time with a configuration that normally uses around 0.05s ...

Comment: There is also GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_PRECONNECTED environment variable to try. But I'm not optimistic as _ALL would logically include them. This one is special for stderr and stdout, which would be the problem area here. To check that your ./exe has the options:
`strings ./exe |  grep BUFFER`

Comment: If they aren't there you need to reconsider your compile options... It could also be that they are slightly different if you are not using gnu fortran.  

Another option to try could be to run your script in foreground. To do so first remove the "exit" command at the end of the script, as it will exit your shell after running. To run in foreground:  
`. ./<your script>`  
Note the '.' at the beginning this is absolute essential

Comment: The problem is fixed, it came from my environnement. I execute using OpenMP parallelisation and i was playing around with chunk size and on my smaller data sets, i had a chunk too big for too little iterations, basicly slowing down the entire program to 1 second

Comment: At least you found what it was :-)